# How to reuse a value for the description *and* the matcher in Specs2?

Tags: scala, specs2

I'm currently using `|>` from scalaz for achieving the following:

```
(4 |> (s => (s + " is smaller than 10" ! (s < 10 must beTrue)))
```

This allows me to reuse the `.toString` of an object inside the description of the test case. But since Specs2 seems to support kind of complicated stuff like extracting things from the source of the tests by scanning the `src` folder --- they must have thought about this particular use case.

There's also the `Given`, `When`, `Then` stuff but it looks extremely verbose.

So how do I reuse the same object for description and matcher? I think my solution is acceptable but the parenthesis are bugging me. In reality it looks like this:

```
(Set((1,2),(3,4)) |> (s => s + " has Set(1,2) as component of 1" ! (graph.componentOf(s,1) must_== Set(1,2))))
```

Answer (score 2):

When the body of the example is very close to the description you can just use "[auto-examples](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.SpecStructure.html#Auto-Examples)":

```
"some examples"     ^
{ 4 must be_<(10) } ^
{ 5 must be_<(10) }
```

In that case, the body of the example is directly used as a description when executed with sbt:

```
[info] some examples
[info] + 4 must be_<(10)
[info] + 5 must be_<(10)
```

Note that I wrote the expectations as `4 must be_<(10)` instead of `(4 < 10) must beTrue` because the failure message is going to be more explicit if something goes wrong:

```
14 is not less than 10
        vs
the value is false
```

If you want to enhance a failure message with even more information you can also use the `aka` operator:

```
 (4 < 10) aka "four < ten" must beTrue
```

Finally, there is a simpler version of Given-When-Then, where you can simply [reuse the description of an example](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.SpecStructure.html#Using+the+Example+description):

```
 "4 is smaller than 10" !  { (s: String) => 
   s.split(" ").head.toInt must be_<(10) 
 }
```

Comment: For your simple GWT case: It's much easier to convert an object to String form then to parse it back from a String. The auto-examples look nice but I'd have to create many custom matchers. Maybe that's the way to go...

Comment: If you have any idea which you think could be supported in specs2, I'm all ears. Otherwise, your approach using functions might just be the right way to go. It is exactly what specs2 intend to support in contrast to JUnit where you can't generate tests from functions.